# Database management in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

I'm making a server with Java that will provide chat services for flash clients. The server will store data about each user on a .txt file somewhere on the server. For example when a user logs in, information about this user is requested to the DatabaseManger class. It will then search through the database and return the information. The point is that when allot of people log in a short amount of time the server is doing allot of checks again and again.
The idea that I want to implement is that a connection class does something like this:

```
String userData = DatabaseManager.getUserData(this.username);
```

The DatabaseManager then doesn't search immediately, it stores this request in an array of requests, then in a fixed interval it goes through the database 1 time and returns data to the clients that requested this. This way when 15 people log in in a second it wont go through all the information 15 times. How to implement this?

Comment: Have you profiled to check that you need to do this?

Comment: it just seems like a better way to do it to me especially since write commands that occur simultaneously could break the system, I want it to periodically update.

Comment: it could break the system because you have choosen the most assbackwards way of doing it. and how do you expect periodical READS to prevent any trouble generated by simultaneous WRITES?

Comment: The idea I had in mind is to make both the reads and writes work on this time-system. Most importantly the writes because to do that I have to make a new .txt file, copy the data into it, delete the old file and rename it. I'd figured it was pretty obvious that this system would also be applied to writes...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use a real DBMS like everyone else on the planet. I'm eager to hear a reason why someone wouldn't choose a DB for this application. I can't think of anything that would prevent it. Back in the day, RDBMS were ungainly, expensive, complicated beasts. Today, they're as readily available as tabloids at the checkout counter.

There are few excuses to not to a DB nowadays, and arguably there are more excuses to use the DB than the file system for most any application.

Comment: thanks for your reply, I am settled on a simple database approach with just a single .txt file to store user data. I would like to know how to implement in Java that a function will wait with returning and that the manager class returns them all on a fixed interval.

Comment: @user1126865: By not using an existing database solution, you're committing yourself to reinventing the wheel for inserting, querying, indexing, caching, concurrency, etc. etc.

Comment: +1. Moreover, having JDBC and transactions on your resume will be much more useful than having a proprietary text-file based persistence mechanism.

Comment: owkay thanks for the information, this alternative approach to my problem seems to be more stable in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

As above I'd recommend using an existing database solution like HSQLDB, you'd be far better off in the long run doing things this way rather than hacking your own solution together.

If you really want to do this anyway, have a look at the [ScheduledExecutorService](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html). You can then fire off a request to the executor service with a delay, and in that delay listen for more data and add it to the query.